# Running sinatra using G-WAN

Tags: sinatra, g-wan

Is it possible to use [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) using [G-wan](http://gwan.com) web server?

if it possible how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `Sinatra` on G-WAN via `CGI`, like shown with the G-WAN extern.c or stream3.c examples used to execute external commands.

Answer (score 0):

Until the (proxy mode/load bancer) is not explained, no, it's not possible to run sinatra on G-WAN

Comment: The reverse-proxy requires that the back-end is a server itself, and in the case of Sinatra, this server might be slower than G-WAN. As a result, using a reverse-proxy might not be the most efficient solution.

Comment: sinatra is fast too ... I can have requests under 5ms ... But I didn't test sinatra CGI mode ... If it have to reload libs each time I'm not sure it's the best way

Comment: 5 ms is a very very long time (just check the loan.c example) so the problem is more about how many such requests you can serve **concurrently**.

Comment: I agree, but running as a cgi should be very much slowest, isn't it? As I said, I never used it using CGI module ... So maybe I'm wrong

Comment: When in doubt, test. There's no substitute to results extracted from reality.